# Update minimum spanning tree if edge is removed

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, runtime, big-o

I am having trouble with the following question:

Assume we have already found a minimum spanning tree `T` for a weighted, undirected graph `G = (V,E)`. We would like to be able to efficiently update `T` should `G` be altered slightly.

An edge is removed from `G` to produce a new graph such that the new graph is still connected. Give an algorithm that uses `T` to find a minimum spanning tree for the new graph in `O(|E|)` time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everything is still connected and only one edge has been removed, then most (and maybe all) of the spanning tree remains the same.  Attempt to construct the same minimum spanning tree, and if the edge that was removed was part of the spanning tree, grab the next smallest edge that completes the minimum spanning tree.

Comment: I drew a simple example and I am having trouble writing the algorithm. How to find the next smallest edge in O(|E|) time? Do we run Kruskal's algorithm or Prim's algorithm?

Comment: Check to see if the edge in T still remains in G.  If an edge in T was removed as reflected by this check, then return the edge for the affected node that is the newest smallest weighted value.  Hopefully this makes sense.

The number of edges in T to check will be <= edges in G since it is a subgraph.  Checking the edges out of a node in G will also be less than |E|.  Should give an O(|E|) algorithm.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense now. Thanks!